# error in installing mysql and connecting to it in wsl2 (Ubunto 22.04)

Tags: mysql, mysql-connection

I am trying to install MySQL on Ubuntu 22.04 (WSL2) and these are the steps that I did:

1- Installing mysql server:

```
root@mans-pc:~# sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [13.4 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [870 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe Translation-en [169 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [17.5 kB]
Fetched 1,406 kB in 2s (671 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
root@mans-pc:~# sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libclone-perl libencode-locale-perl libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 libfcgi-bin libfcgi-perl
  libfcgi0ldbl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl
  libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libmecab2 libprotobuf-lite23 libtimedate-perl liburi-perl mecab-ipadic
  mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils mysql-client-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-common mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0
Suggested packages:
  libdata-dump-perl libipc-sharedcache-perl libbusiness-isbn-perl libwww-perl mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libclone-perl libencode-locale-perl libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 libfcgi-bin libfcgi-perl
  libfcgi0ldbl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl
  libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libmecab2 libprotobuf-lite23 libtimedate-perl liburi-perl mecab-ipadic
  mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils mysql-client-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-8.0
  mysql-server-core-8.0
0 upgraded, 28 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 29.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 242 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 mysql-common all 5.8+1.0.8 [7,212 B]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-core-8.0 amd64 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 [2,677 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-8.0 amd64 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 [22.7 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 amd64 2.1.12-stable-1build3 [7,642 B]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libmecab2 amd64 0.996-14build9 [199 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libprotobuf-lite23 amd64 3.12.4-1ubuntu7 [208 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-core-8.0 amd64 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 [17.5 MB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-8.0 amd64 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 [1,427 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libhtml-tagset-perl all 3.20-4 [12.5 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 liburi-perl all 5.10-1 [78.8 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libhtml-parser-perl amd64 3.76-1build2 [88.4 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libcgi-pm-perl all 4.54-1 [188 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libfcgi0ldbl amd64 2.4.2-2build2 [28.0 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libfcgi-perl amd64 0.82+ds-1build1 [22.8 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libcgi-fast-perl all 1:2.15-1 [10.5 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libclone-perl amd64 0.45-1build3 [11.0 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libencode-locale-perl all 1.05-1.1 [11.8 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libfcgi-bin amd64 2.4.2-2build2 [11.2 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libhtml-template-perl all 2.97-1.1 [59.1 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libtimedate-perl all 2.3300-2 [34.0 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libhttp-date-perl all 6.05-1 [9,920 B]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libio-html-perl all 1.004-2 [15.4 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 liblwp-mediatypes-perl all 6.04-1 [19.5 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libhttp-message-perl all 6.36-1 [76.8 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 mecab-utils amd64 0.996-14build9 [4,850 B]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 mecab-ipadic all 2.7.0-20070801+main-3 [6,718 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 mecab-ipadic-utf8 all 2.7.0-20070801+main-3 [4,384 B]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 mysql-server all 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 [9,458 B]
Fetched 29.5 MB in 6s (4,860 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 58973 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-mysql-common_5.8+1.0.8_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.8+1.0.8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-8.0.
Preparing to unpack .../1-mysql-client-core-8.0_8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-8.0 (8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-8.0.
Preparing to unpack .../2-mysql-client-8.0_8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-8.0 (8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libevent-pthreads-2.1-7:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../3-libevent-pthreads-2.1-7_2.1.12-stable-1build3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libevent-pthreads-2.1-7:amd64 (2.1.12-stable-1build3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmecab2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../4-libmecab2_0.996-14build9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmecab2:amd64 (0.996-14build9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libprotobuf-lite23:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../5-libprotobuf-lite23_3.12.4-1ubuntu7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libprotobuf-lite23:amd64 (3.12.4-1ubuntu7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-8.0.
Preparing to unpack .../6-mysql-server-core-8.0_8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.8+1.0.8) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-8.0.
(Reading database ... 59187 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-mysql-server-8.0_8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-tagset-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libhtml-tagset-perl_3.20-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-tagset-perl (3.20-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liburi-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../02-liburi-perl_5.10-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking liburi-perl (5.10-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-parser-perl:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libhtml-parser-perl_3.76-1build2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-parser-perl:amd64 (3.76-1build2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcgi-pm-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libcgi-pm-perl_4.54-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libcgi-pm-perl (4.54-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfcgi0ldbl:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libfcgi0ldbl_2.4.2-2build2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfcgi0ldbl:amd64 (2.4.2-2build2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfcgi-perl:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libfcgi-perl_0.82+ds-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfcgi-perl:amd64 (0.82+ds-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcgi-fast-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libcgi-fast-perl_1%3a2.15-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libclone-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libclone-perl_0.45-1build3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libclone-perl (0.45-1build3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libencode-locale-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libencode-locale-perl_1.05-1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libencode-locale-perl (1.05-1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfcgi-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libfcgi-bin_2.4.2-2build2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfcgi-bin (2.4.2-2build2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-template-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libhtml-template-perl_2.97-1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-template-perl (2.97-1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtimedate-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../12-libtimedate-perl_2.3300-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libtimedate-perl (2.3300-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhttp-date-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libhttp-date-perl_6.05-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhttp-date-perl (6.05-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libio-html-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../14-libio-html-perl_1.004-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libio-html-perl (1.004-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblwp-mediatypes-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../15-liblwp-mediatypes-perl_6.04-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking liblwp-mediatypes-perl (6.04-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhttp-message-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../16-libhttp-message-perl_6.36-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhttp-message-perl (6.36-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mecab-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../17-mecab-utils_0.996-14build9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mecab-utils (0.996-14build9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mecab-ipadic.
Preparing to unpack .../18-mecab-ipadic_2.7.0-20070801+main-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking mecab-ipadic (2.7.0-20070801+main-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mecab-ipadic-utf8.
Preparing to unpack .../19-mecab-ipadic-utf8_2.7.0-20070801+main-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking mecab-ipadic-utf8 (2.7.0-20070801+main-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../20-mysql-server_8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Setting up libmecab2:amd64 (0.996-14build9) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-8.0 (8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Setting up libfcgi0ldbl:amd64 (2.4.2-2build2) ...
Setting up libclone-perl (0.45-1build3) ...
Setting up libhtml-tagset-perl (3.20-4) ...
Setting up liblwp-mediatypes-perl (6.04-1) ...
Setting up libfcgi-bin (2.4.2-2build2) ...
Setting up libencode-locale-perl (1.05-1.1) ...
Setting up libprotobuf-lite23:amd64 (3.12.4-1ubuntu7) ...
Setting up mecab-utils (0.996-14build9) ...
Setting up libio-html-perl (1.004-2) ...
Setting up libtimedate-perl (2.3300-2) ...
Setting up mysql-client-8.0 (8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Setting up libfcgi-perl:amd64 (0.82+ds-1build1) ...
Setting up liburi-perl (5.10-1) ...
Setting up libevent-pthreads-2.1-7:amd64 (2.1.12-stable-1build3) ...
Setting up libhttp-date-perl (6.05-1) ...
Setting up mecab-ipadic (2.7.0-20070801+main-3) ...
Compiling IPA dictionary for Mecab.  This takes long time...
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/unk.def ... 40
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|
/usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/model.def is not found. skipped.
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.others.csv ... 151
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Conjunction.csv ... 171
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adverb.csv ... 3032
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Suffix.csv ... 1393
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.name.csv ... 34202
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp-col.csv ... 91
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.number.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Auxil.csv ... 199
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.place.csv ... 72999
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Filler.csv ... 19
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.proper.csv ... 27328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Others.csv ... 2
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.nai.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Prefix.csv ... 221
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.org.csv ... 16668
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.csv ... 60477
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Symbol.csv ... 208
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp.csv ... 146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adverbal.csv ... 795
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adnominal.csv ... 135
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Interjection.csv ... 252
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.demonst.csv ... 120
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adj.csv ... 27210
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Verb.csv ... 130750
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.verbal.csv ... 12146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adjv.csv ... 3328
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/matrix.def ... 1316x1316
emitting matrix      : 100% |###########################################|

done!
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Setting up mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Setting up mecab-ipadic-utf8 (2.7.0-20070801+main-3) ...
Compiling IPA dictionary for Mecab.  This takes long time...
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/unk.def ... 40
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|
/usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/model.def is not found. skipped.
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.others.csv ... 151
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Conjunction.csv ... 171
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adverb.csv ... 3032
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Suffix.csv ... 1393
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.name.csv ... 34202
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp-col.csv ... 91
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.number.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Auxil.csv ... 199
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.place.csv ... 72999
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Filler.csv ... 19
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.proper.csv ... 27328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Others.csv ... 2
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.nai.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Prefix.csv ... 221
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.org.csv ... 16668
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.csv ... 60477
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Symbol.csv ... 208
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp.csv ... 146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adverbal.csv ... 795
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adnominal.csv ... 135
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Interjection.csv ... 252
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.demonst.csv ... 120
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adj.csv ... 27210
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Verb.csv ... 130750
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.verbal.csv ... 12146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adjv.csv ... 3328
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/matrix.def ... 1316x1316
emitting matrix      : 100% |###########################################|

done!
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8 to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Setting up libhtml-parser-perl:amd64 (3.76-1build2) ...
Setting up libhttp-message-perl (6.36-1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                             [ OK ]
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 30381
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service → /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service.
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
Setting up libcgi-pm-perl (4.54-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.97-1.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server (8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Setting up libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libcuda.so.1 is not a symbolic link

Scanning processes...
Scanning processor microcode...
Scanning linux images...

Failed to retrieve available kernel versions.

The processor microcode seems to be up-to-date.

No services need to be restarted.

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.
```

try to run the mysql CLI to change password for root:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
```

What is the problem and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: daemons work differently or not at all in WSL**

In a real Ubuntu (or other Linux/Unix) operating system, the operating system runs programs as and when directed by user commands but also runs some programs automatically under an 'init system'; traditionally these latter programs are called daemons and often have a `d` at the end of their name. MySQL server is such a program, hence the name `mysqld` in two of your log messages. Recent versions of Ubuntu specifically use an init system called `systemd` (which itself is a daemon, or perhaps meta-daemon) and the `mysql-server` *package* not only installs the program and related files but sets up configuration so that systemd will automatically run mysqld, as a daemon, when the system boots (unless/until you disable it, or uninstall).

WSL does not boot or really run an OS like Ubuntu; rather it runs *programs* in an environment that mimics very closely the environment on a real Ubuntu system. Originally it never ran any init system at all, and thus not systemd, thus not anything that runs under system like mysqld. Apparently a very recent version on Win11 *can* run systemd, but not by default, and since I don't have Win11 I can't test or confirm.

Thus to use mysql (or another daemon) under WSL you must either

1. start it explicitly yourself with a command like `sudo service mysqld start` on first use after Windows boot or WSL restart (per distro if more than one)
2. set up your WSL distro(s) to explicitly start it -- in some recent versions you can configure WSL itself to do this with `[boot]`, otherwise you can put commands in your shell profile (such as `.bash_profile`) to start it *if it is not already running*
3. set up your Windows system to explicitly tell WSL to start it, such as a Startup item in your profile, a Task Scheduler job, etc.; depending on details you may need to check first that it is not already running
4. if you have Win11 and a new-enough WSL, just enable systemd and then the configuration done by the `mysql-server` package should work (although you *might* need to go through the install again to get the correct configuration, I don't know)

For some options see:
https://superuser.com/questions/1343558/how-to-make-wsl-run-services-at-startup
https://superuser.com/questions/1701853/how-to-enable-a-service-to-start-with-wsl2
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1355633/how-to-start-a-specific-service-when-ubuntu-is-started-on-wsl2